# Looking for the name of a physical phenomenon in fluids' mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, terminology

I have not even an idea about how I would search for that on Google, that is why I'm trying my chance here.
As electrical engineer I have no clue about fluid mechanics. We all now that when water is pumped very fast into firefighters tube, it gets very rigid and tends to be straight. What is this effect called, I'm interested in doing some research about the forces applied by such a tube from its initial folded position to the final position.

Thanks

Comment: To start with, the water pressure in the hoses is above 100 psi. This forces the hose to expand to it's maximum size, which happens to be a straight tube. Changing the direction would require a significant force.

Comment: perhaps you're looking for turgidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the kink it had momentum density $\frac{\vec{p}}{V} = \frac{\rho V \vec{v}  }{V} = \rho \vec{v_1}$; afterward $\rho \vec{v_2}$. The change in momentum density is $\rho (\vec{v_2} - \vec{v_1})$.

Multiplying by $A v t$ (the volume that moves past the kink in time $t$), we get the change in momentum that must be supplied to maintain the kink (i.e. the force at the kink) over time $t$, which means that just multiplying by $Av$ is the force at the kink:
$$ F = A \rho v^2 (\hat{v_2} - \hat{v_2})\,. $$

Now stick in some estimates for a firehose, assuming a 60 degree bend to make the trigonometry easy.

$$ \begin{align*}
A &= 80 \,\mathrm{cm^2} = 0.008 \,\mathrm{m^2}\\
\rho &= 1 \,\mathrm{g/cm^3} = 1000 \,\mathrm{kg/m^3}\\
v &= 10 \,\mathrm{m/s} \,,
\end{align*} $$
(I've tried to chose a reasonable velocity based on how high you can spray from the ground, but I don't really know what that value should be.)

Anyway, with those figures I get $800 \,\mathrm{N}$ which is roughly the weight of $80 \,\mathrm{kg}$ or enough force to require a strong adult person to have a chance of holding, but it could easily knock a person over.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it much easier to understand. But where did you use the 60 degrees assumption?

Comment: @Mehdi The sixty degree assumption makes the vector difference easy. If both the velocities are the same magnitude, then the difference has that same magnitude (think equilateral triangle).

Comment: Oh yeah I see now. Do you also have an idea how to calculate the force generated by a spiral pipe where water flows? like the first picture in this forum http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=681441 suppose we have a water pump at one end of the pipe and that the pipe is flexible but with fixed diameter. What force would it apply in axial direction of the spiral?